# How can i configure customer Middle Name/Initial as a required field in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, required

If it is possible Customer Middle Name/Initial is required, Now I use this code to required this field but can not work

```
<?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
<?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
    <div class="field name-middlename">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"><em>*</em><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

so if any suggestions guy's so, please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `required-entry` in the class attribute of the `input` field will make the field required.

Try to add below code

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

Comment: Hi @sumit 
Thanks for the helping this code is work now.

Answer (score 3):

To make the the middle name required add

```
class="input-text required-entry"
```

something like this :

```
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
```

Comment: Hi @Yigen 
Also, thank you for the right answer you are also right.

Comment: Glad it helped !